# Removing placeholder for drop area when cursor not in drop zone in material cdk drag & drop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

When drag item moves over the drop area, the area is highlighted and created a placeholder for the same. But if the mouse point is moving away the drop area and release the drop the item. It still drop into the drop zone.

[Drag Drop Issue Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeGbE.gif)

**Expected behavior**:

Once the mouse pointer is move away from the drop zone and the user release the mouse or cancel the drag. It should go back to the drag start list.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxxnargngbb?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to check, when the item was dropped, whether it was allowed container or not.

We can use [CdkDrag](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag)'s `cdkDragDropped` event. `cdkDragDropped` emits the object which has a type of interface [`CdkDragDrop`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop). `CdkDragDrop` has a property called `isPointerOverContainer: boolean`, which returns whether the user's pointer was over the container when the item was dropped.

I have created a sample code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjjbyr).

Basically, what I did was:

1. Listened to `cdkDragDropped` event of `cdkDrag` element : `<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag (cdkDragDropped)="dragDropped($event)">{{item}}</div>`
2. In `dragDropped` function, I stored the flag: `dragDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
   this.isPointerOverContainer = event.isPointerOverContainer;
   }`
3. In `drop` function, I checked the same flag : `if (this.isPointerOverContainer) {...} else { //dropped outside }`

Currently, the item will get back to its original position if dropped outside. But, the animation is not handled, you can explore that part.

Comment: isPointerOverContainer  helped in my query, But still placeholder is there even after i'm hovering out of drop container.

Comment: Yeah, placeholder and animations aren't properly handled. You will need to check out events of cdkDropList, those might help.

Comment: fyi, this won't work on a basic cdkDrag element (without a container aka cdkDropList), but *cdkDragReleased* and *cdkDragEnded* will. `<div
      cdkDrag
      cdkDragBoundary=".container-like-elem"
      (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
      (cdkDragReleased)="dragReleased($event)"
      (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)">` then `dragReleased(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log('cdkDragReleased', event);
  }`

Comment: Here's a simple solution to remove the placeholder when pointer isn't over the container.
```:host {
  .cdk-drop-list {
    &:not(:hover)>.cdk-drag-placeholder {
      @apply hidden;
    }
}```